# Data concurrency SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I am working with a Finance application. It's not developed by me, but I have to resolve a cuncurrency problem. Users launch some analysis using a Windows Forms application and then, on a temporary table, for every analysis an id is generated by separate id column. Then data is sent to some stored procedures for calculations and modification on a different table. Finally calculated data is stored on different tables and the id is removed from the temporary table.

The problem is that only one user can launch an analysis at a time. Others have to wait because the application says the analysis id is already present. Actually, it was designed this way and now I have to resolve this problem, so any user can launch analysis at the same time. Please guide.

Comment: Title says concurrency, body of the question seems like it. But you said also "I have to solve a currency problem". Given this is a financial app, could it be a typo for concurrency? ;) Any **you could try on [transaction isolation levels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/02/20/concurrency-series-basics-of-transaction-isolation-levels.aspx)**

Comment: Also you could take a look at how the analysis id is generated and stored, as there's a conflict with the id's.

Comment: sounds like a coding issue, not specifically a SQL Server issue.

If the code was designed specifically to be single user only, you will have to post the code here - if the code is too complex to post or is company intellectual property then you are on your own.

Comment: hi bonCodigo  i have to fix it in a way that any one can use application at any time or same time , according to my understandings only problem is that id which is generated and used throughout the calculation however i think in somewhere in some update case its locking the data , i tried to generate two ids and launched the two at same time but what happens somewhere it gives me primary key violation error insert fails message

Comment: its more than 10000 line code 30 to 40 store procedures which are doing calculations however major logic is in temporary tables it get user parameters and creates a unique column id showidentity and then its use everywhere same id until it finish calculations and finally it  remove id i will try to paste some code here

Comment: Can you modify your code in such way that each user use his own temporary table. It seemed that now they use the same one global temporary table.

Comment: yes you are right there Serg its only one temporary table where id is placed and remains that table until it finish calculations , but i am not getting your idea temporary table for each User can you please share it in detail